# Cosmos DB query documents with nested arrays

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmos db database with documents like this:

```
{
"id": "0001144204-10-023984",
"schemaVersion": "X0303",
"documentType": "4",
"periodOfReport": "2010-04-29",
"notSubjectToSection16": "0",
"issuer": {
    "issuerCik": "0001076167",
    "issuerName": "ADOLOR CORP",
    "issuerTradingSymbol": "ADLR"
},
"reportingOwner": [
    {
        "reportingOwnerId": {
            "rptOwnerCik": "0001317493",
            "rptOwnerName": "14159 capital (GP), LLC"
        },
        "reportingOwnerAddress": {
            "rptOwnerStreet1": "667 MADISON AVENUE, 17TH FLOOR",
            "rptOwnerStreet2": null,
            "rptOwnerCity": "NEW YORK",
            "rptOwnerState": "NY",
            "rptOwnerZipCode": "US 10021",
            "rptOwnerStateDescription": null
        },
        "reportingOwnerRelationship": {
            "isDirector": "0",
            "isOfficer": "0",
            "isTenPercentOwner": "1",
            "isOther": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "reportingOwnerId": {
            "rptOwnerCik": "0001087939",
            "rptOwnerName": "BAKER JULIAN"
        },
        "reportingOwnerAddress": {
            "rptOwnerStreet1": "667 MADISON AVENUE, 17TH FLOOR",
            "rptOwnerStreet2": null,
            "rptOwnerCity": "NEW YORK",
            "rptOwnerState": "NY",
            "rptOwnerZipCode": "US 10021",
            "rptOwnerStateDescription": null
        },
        "reportingOwnerRelationship": {
            "isDirector": "0",
            "isOfficer": "0",
            "isTenPercentOwner": "1",
            "isOther": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "reportingOwnerId": {
            "rptOwnerCik": "0001087940",
            "rptOwnerName": "BAKER FELIX"
        },
        "reportingOwnerAddress": {
            "rptOwnerStreet1": "667 MADISON AVENUE, 17TH FLOOR",
            "rptOwnerStreet2": null,
            "rptOwnerCity": "NEW YORK",
            "rptOwnerState": "NY",
            "rptOwnerZipCode": "US 10021",
            "rptOwnerStateDescription": null
        },
        "reportingOwnerRelationship": {
            "isDirector": "0",
            "isOfficer": "0",
            "isTenPercentOwner": "1",
            "isOther": "0"
        }
    }
],
"nonDerivativeTable": {
    "nonDerivativeTransaction": [
        {
            "securityTitle": {
                "value": "Common Stock",
                "footnoteId": [
                    {
                        "@id": "F1"
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "F2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "transactionDate": {
                "value": "2010-04-29"
            },
            "deemedExecutionDate": null,
            "transactionCoding": {
                "transactionFormType": "4",
                "transactionCode": "P",
                "equitySwapInvolved": "0"
            },
            "transactionAmounts": {
                "transactionShares": {
                    "value": "124"
                },
                "transactionPricePerShare": {
                    "value": "1.9387"
                },
                "transactionAcquiredDisposedCode": {
                    "value": "A"
                }
            },
            "postTransactionAmounts": {
                "sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction": {
                    "value": "159135"
                }
            },
            "ownershipNature": {
                "directOrIndirectOwnership": {
                    "value": "I"
                },
                "natureOfOwnership": {
                    "value": "Through Partnership",
                    "footnoteId": {
                        "@id": "F3"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "securityTitle": {
                "value": "Common Stock",
                "footnoteId": [
                    {
                        "@id": "F1"
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "F2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "transactionDate": {
                "value": "2010-04-30"
            },
            "deemedExecutionDate": null,
            "transactionCoding": {
                "transactionFormType": "4",
                "transactionCode": "P",
                "equitySwapInvolved": "0"
            },
            "transactionAmounts": {
                "transactionShares": {
                    "value": "970"
                },
                "transactionPricePerShare": {
                    "value": "1.9876"
                },
                "transactionAcquiredDisposedCode": {
                    "value": "A"
                }
            },
            "postTransactionAmounts": {
                "sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction": {
                    "value": "160105"
                }
            },
            "ownershipNature": {
                "directOrIndirectOwnership": {
                    "value": "I"
                },
                "natureOfOwnership": {
                    "value": "Through Partnership",
                    "footnoteId": {
                        "@id": "F3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"footnotes": {
    "footnote": [
        {
            "@id": "F1",
            "#text": "In addition to 14159 Capital (GP), LLC, this Form 4 is being filed jointly by Julian C. Baker and Felix J. Baker each of whom has the same business address as 14159 Capital (GP), LLC and may be deemed to have a pecuniary interest in securities owned by it. Because of certain relationships with other security holders of the Issuer, the Reporting Persons are filing solely for informational purposes as if they were a member of a group of such shareholders. (Continued in footnote 2)."
        },
        {
            "@id": "F2",
            "#text": "However, the Reporting Persons disclaim that they or any other person or persons, in fact constitute a \"group\" for purposes of Section 13(d)(3) of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934, as amended, or Rule 13d-5 thereunder or that they are the beneficial owners of securities owned by any such other persons and each of them disclaim beneficial ownership or securities reported herein except to the extent of their pecuniary interest, if any, therein."
        },
        {
            "@id": "F3",
            "#text": "Represents securities owned directly by 14159, L.P., a limited partnership the sole general partner of which is 14159 Capital, L.P., a limited partnership the sole general partner of which is 14159 Capital (GP), LLC. Julian C. Baker and Felix J. Baker are controlling members of 14159 Capital (GP), LLC."
        }
    ]
},
"ownerSignature": [
    {
        "signatureName": "/s/ Julian C. Baker, as Managing Member of 14519 Capital (GP), LLC",
        "signatureDate": "2010-05-03"
    },
    {
        "signatureName": "/s/ Julian C. Baker",
        "signatureDate": "2010-05-03"
    },
    {
        "signatureName": "/s/ Felix J. Baker",
        "signatureDate": "2010-05-03"
    }
],
"_rid": "VGpbAOXASdcHAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/VGpbAA==/colls/VGpbAOXASdc=/docs/VGpbAOXASdcHAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"4b00a6db-0000-1500-0000-6147667b0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1632069243
```

}

However, the reportingOwner is not always an array, so some documents looks like this:

```
{
"id": "0001209191-10-029977",
"schemaVersion": "X0303",
"documentType": "4",
"periodOfReport": "2010-05-21",
"notSubjectToSection16": "0",
"issuer": {
    "issuerCik": "0000886475",
    "issuerName": "'mktg, inc.'",
    "issuerTradingSymbol": "CMKG"
},
"reportingOwner": {
    "reportingOwnerId": {
        "rptOwnerCik": "0001452691",
        "rptOwnerName": "Horsey Charles W."
    },
    "reportingOwnerAddress": {
        "rptOwnerStreet1": "75 NINTH AVENUE",
        "rptOwnerStreet2": "3RD FLOOR",
        "rptOwnerCity": "NEW YORK",
        "rptOwnerState": "NY",
        "rptOwnerZipCode": "10011",
        "rptOwnerStateDescription": null
    },
    "reportingOwnerRelationship": {
        "isDirector": "1",
        "isOfficer": "1",
        "isTenPercentOwner": "0",
        "isOther": "0",
        "officerTitle": "President"
    }
},
"derivativeTable": {
    "derivativeTransaction": {
        "securityTitle": {
            "value": "Stock Option (Right to Buy)"
        },
        "conversionOrExercisePrice": {
            "value": "0.43"
        },
        "transactionDate": {
            "value": "2010-05-21"
        },
        "deemedExecutionDate": null,
        "transactionCoding": {
            "transactionFormType": "4",
            "transactionCode": "A",
            "equitySwapInvolved": "0"
        },
        "transactionTimeliness": {
            "value": null
        },
        "transactionAmounts": {
            "transactionShares": {
                "value": "953284"
            },
            "transactionPricePerShare": {
                "value": "0.00"
            },
            "transactionAcquiredDisposedCode": {
                "value": "A"
            }
        },
        "exerciseDate": {
            "footnoteId": {
                "@id": "F1"
            }
        },
        "expirationDate": {
            "value": "2020-04-01"
        },
        "underlyingSecurity": {
            "underlyingSecurityTitle": {
                "value": "Common Stock"
            },
            "underlyingSecurityShares": {
                "value": "953284"
            }
        },
        "postTransactionAmounts": {
            "sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction": {
                "value": "953284"
            }
        },
        "ownershipNature": {
            "directOrIndirectOwnership": {
                "value": "D"
            }
        }
    }
},
"footnotes": {
    "footnote": {
        "@id": "F1",
        "#text": "This option vests and becomes exercisable (i) on April 1, 2011 as to 25% of the shares; and (ii) subject to achieving annual EBITDA targets set forth in the Option Agreement between the Issuer and the Reporting Person, as to an additional 25% of the shares on each of April 1, 2012, April 1, 2013 and April 1, 2014."
    }
},
"remarks": null,
"ownerSignature": {
    "signatureName": "/s/Charles W. Horsey",
    "signatureDate": "2010-05-24"
},
"_rid": "VGpbAOXASdcBAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/VGpbAA==/colls/VGpbAOXASdc=/docs/VGpbAOXASdcBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"4b0092db-0000-1500-0000-6147667a0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1632069242
```

}

Now I need to query the Database to look for specific reportingOwner.reportingOwnerId.rptOwnerName. The issue is that the query depends on the type of reportingOwner. If it is an array I have to check if the array contains the name and if its is an dictionary I can access the name directly.
I tried multiple approaches. First I thought about ternery conditions like this:

`SELECT IS_ARRAY(c.reportingOwner) ? c.reportingOwner : c.reportingOwner.reportingOwnerId.rptOwnerName AS own FROM c WHERE IS_ARRAY(c.reportingOwner) ? 'name' IN c.reportingOwner.reportingOwnerId.rptOwnerName : c.reportingOwner LIKE 'name'`

However this wasn't successful. Then I tried using JOINs but this only gives the documents where the reportingOwner is an array:

`SELECT a.reportingOwnerId FROM c JOIN a IN c.reportingOwner WHERE 'name' IN a.reportingOwnerId.rptOwnerName`

Do you have any ideas how I can query for a specific name?

Comment: You have two schemas, so I really think you'd need two separate queries. Might be worth doing some schema migration to create a consistent data schema. How you approach that really is up to you...

Comment: Also, you'd get more help if you reduced your examples to minimal relevant structure to show your problem.